# How would light from a blue or red star affect the way we see?

Tags: star, light

How would things look if we saw them through the light of a blue or red star?
Would there be any changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it would be influenced. Right now, our vision is already influenced by that [massive blue sky above us](http://patarnott.com/atms749/pdf/blueSkyHumanResponse.pdf). The human visual system corresponds to the large influx of blue light that gets scattered in the atmosphere. Having a red or a blue star would probably also have some influence, as would have a different kind of atmosphere (which is not mainly nitrogen and oxygen). The brain would probably compensate, but the rods in the eye would have a different composition.